# Equivalence/(Partial order) relation or any other suitable known relations?

Tags: graph-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $G$ be an indirected graph, let $V(G)$ and $E(G)$ be the  set of vertices and edges of $G$, respectively. Define a relation $R$ on $G$ as: for all $v\in V(G)$ and $e\in E(G)$, $vRe$ if and only if $e$ is incident on $v$ and vice versa. Further, considering that $(v, v)=v$ i.e., the self loop $(v, v)$ coincides with the point $v$. Now, i wish to show that $R$ is an equivalence relation or any other suitable known relation on $G$.
**My effort:** (1) Let $v\in V(G)$, then we can say that $v$ is incident on $v$  i.e., $vRv$; but what when $e\in E(G)$ is choosen?
(2) Let $v\in V(G)$ and $e\in E(G)$, then $vRe\implies eRv$ or, for any $u, v\in V(G)$, $uRv\implies vRu$; but i have no idea of symmetricity when $v\in V(G)$ and $e\in E(G)$ is choosen or $e\in E(G)$ and $f\in E(G)$ is choosen? Lastly, transitive law seems to be failed. Please someone suggest me what type of the relation $R$ would be on $G$?

Comment: Can you formalize the definition of your relation more clearly? For example it says nothing about whether two edges are ever related to each other. If not the relation is certainly not reflexive.

Comment: @Ethan MacBrough i couldn't define the relation between edges. Could you help me to define one?

Comment: That makes no sense. I could definitely the relation on edges arbitrarily. Is your question whether or not there exists a way to define this relation that makes it an equivalence relation?

Answer (score 1):

Well, its not an equivalence relation. Its an inhomogeneous relation on $V\times E$. For an equivalence relation, you need to start from a homogeneous relation, say a relation on $V\times V$.

A prominent equivalence relation on an undirected graph $G$ is defined on $V\times V$, with $uRv$ iff there exists a path in $G$ between $u$ and $v$. The equivalence classes are then the connected components of $G$.

Comment: It looks to me like OP was trying to define the relation on $(V\cup E)\times (V\cup E)$.